# Python Asyncio SNMP script stops processing responses after 400 responses

Tags: python-3.x, windows, python-asyncio, pysnmp

I have a 3rd party script that polls devices via SNMP using pysnmp in batches of 100 using asyncio. Currently the script processes about the first 400 responses and then ignores the rest. I know I'm getting the other responses as I can see them in Wireshark.

I know there are limitations of asyncio on Windows, but I dont know asyncio enough to know if I'm running into those issues or not.

Has anyone run into this or something similar?

- Python 3.8.10
- pysnmp 4.4.12

Comment: Do you do any heavy CPU bound operations with the data you've received? If you do so, it probably could be caused by such operations, I had same problem with aiohttp server and it looked for me as the server was frozen.

Comment: Nope, the data received is just logged. CPU and RAM usage is low, the machine is basically idling.